# different ways to perform this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm struggling to find efficient way to perform the following problem.

I have 3 tables:

**1)** `Events` tbl that keeps the following data:

[image]

**2)** `Tasks` tbl that keeps the following data:

[image]

The logic is that:

- many Tasks can be assigned to event (but not necessarily event have a
  task)
- event can be defined as phase
- events.event_id is PK, and
  tasks.RelatedGateID it his FK
- tasks.taskID is PK

I want a query that will show the list of events that need to have **one** of the following rules:

either the event is a phase **OR** the event have a task(dont have to be phase)

My current query is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(
    SELECT Event_ID FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            E.Event_ID 
        FROM
            Events E 
        WHERE E.Event_IsPhase = 1
    ) ET UNION
    (
        SELECT 
            T.RelatedGateID
        FROM
            Tasks T
    )
)AS tbl1 LEFT JOIN
Tasks AS tbl2 ON tbl1.Event_ID=tbl2.RelatedGateID
```

*The last `LEFT JOIN` is for additional data that I need have.

My question is : I would like to know if there is different way to do this query (more efficiently) ? (right now It has some performence time issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing query won't return your desired dataset - instead, it will return all task records.

Instead, try:

```
select e.Event_ID, t.*
from Events e
left join Tasks t ON e.Event_ID=t.RelatedGateID
where e.Event_IsPhase = 1 or t.RelatedGateID is not null
```

Comment: I'm confused, this query takes about 3 seconds to performed, (same as my query), but my query call the same table (tasks) two times.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Event_ID
FROM Events e
LEFT JOIN Tasks t on e.Event_ID = t.RelatedGateID
WHERE e.Event_IsPhase = 1 OR t.RelatedGateID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: this query took about 10 seconds to perform (while my query took about 3 sec)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select distinct E.Event_ID from Tasks T, Events E 
WHERE (E.Event_ID = T.RelatedGateID) or 
(E.Event_IsPhase = 1)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This query took me 53 seconds(!) while my query took me about 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.Event_ID  FROM Events E left outer join Tasks AS tbl2 ON tbl1.Event_ID=tbl2.RelatedGateID WHERE E.Event_IsPhase = 1 OR COUNT(tasks.taskID) > 0 GROUP BY (E.Event_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one:

```
SELECT Event_ID FROM 
(
    SELECT  Event_ID,
    (select top 1 T.RelatedGateID from Tasks T where T.RelatedGateID=l1.Event_ID) as par 
    FROM Events l1 
    WHERE l1.Event_IsPhase=1
) l2 
WHERE l2.par IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: are you sure, you made everything right? I've checked this one before posting on my own table. It takes all Events with l1.Event_IsPhase=1, then it takes top 1 from Tasks connected by Event_ID or returns NULL if it is empty, and the result is filtered by WHERE l2.par IS NOT NULL.

Comment: if it is possible, could you post the time results of all answers

Comment: I did, see comments of each answer.